# Crop Image before capturing image from camera plugin in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using camera plugin to capture image, in flutter. But I want to crop the image from bottom and top to upload only that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [image_cropper](https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper) Library after capture image

```
import 'package:image_cropper/image_cropper.dart';

File croppedFile = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
  sourcePath: imageFile.path,
  aspectRatioPresets: [
    CropAspectRatioPreset.square,
    CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio3x2,
    CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
    CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
    CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9
  ],
  androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
      toolbarTitle: 'Cropper',
      toolbarColor: Colors.deepOrange,
      toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
      initAspectRatio: CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
      lockAspectRatio: false),
  iosUiSettings: IOSUiSettings(
    minimumAspectRatio: 1.0,
  )
);
```

**Optional parameters**

- maxWidth: maximum cropped image width.
- maxHeight: maximum cropped image height.
- aspectRatio: controls the aspect ratio of crop bounds. If this values
  is set, the cropper is locked and user can't change the aspect ratio
  of crop bounds.
- aspectRatioPresets: controls the list of aspect ratios in the crop
  menu view. In Android, you can set the initialized aspect ratio when
  starting the cropper by setting the value of
  AndroidUiSettings.initAspectRatio.
- cropStyle: controls the style of crop bounds, it can be rectangle or
  circle style (default is CropStyle.rectangle).
- compressFormat: the format of result image, png or jpg (default is
  ImageCompressFormat.jpg).
- compressQuality: the value [0 - 100] to control the quality of image
  compression.
- androidUiSettings: controls UI customization on Android. See Android
  customization.
- iosUiSettings: controls UI customization on iOS. See iOS
  customization.